# Mocking a class during import with Pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

How do I correctly mock out a class during import using pytest?
For example:

```
#main_module.py

    from james import John

    class Fish:
      def run():
        return John()


#test_main_module.py
    @patch('path/to/main_module/where/John/was/used')
    def test_main_module_uses_mork(mocker):
      MockJohn = mocker.Mock()
      assert type(Fish().run()) == MockJohn
```

Comment: The code breaks because it tries to import John from james everytime. I would have it use the MockJohn rather than trying to import John.

Comment: `@patch('main_module.John')` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks. My error was to use "main_module.james.John"